# python imported global variables immutable

Tags: python, global-variables, ipython, python-module

I have a python module e.g. myModule in a subfolder and I have two files:

`__init__.py`:

```
from _auxiliary import *
```

`_auxiliary.py`:

```
myvar=False

def initialize():
    global myvar
    myvar=5
```

Now in ipython when I run:

```
>> import myModule
>> myModule.initialize()
```

the variable myModule.myvar is unchanged i.e. `False`

This does not happen if I put everything in `__init__.py`

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: why do you want to use a global variable such as `myvar` in the first place?

Comment: I am writing a module that manages connections to a server, and the global variable stores the object that manages the connections

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that globals in Python are global to a module, not across all modules. (This is a bit different from other languages and can cause some confusion).

An easy way to solve this (there are some others) is to define a getter method in the original module, in your case:

```
_myvar=False

def initialize():
    global _myvar
    _myvar=5

def myvar():
    global _myvar
    return _myvar
```

So you can access the `_myvar`instance with the *correct* value from whatever module.

```
import myModule
myModule.initialize()
print("myvar value:", myModule.myvar())
```

Previous code will show "myvar value: 5"

Answer (score 0):

[Python - Visibility of global variables in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/python-visibility-of-global-variables-from-imported-modules)

The problem is that globality is relatve to the module in question.

You could import _auxiliary directly:

```
from mymodule import _auxiliary
_auxiliary.initialize()
print _auxiliary.myvar
```