# Configuration variables for a collection of scripts in Python

Tags: python, variables, configuration, module

I have a collection of scripts written in Python. Each of them can be executed independently. However, most of the time they should be executed one after the other, so there is a `MainScript.py` which calls them in the appropriate order. Each script has some configurable variables (let's call them `Root_Dir`, `Data_Dir` and `LinWinFlag`). If this collection of scripts is moved to a different computer, or different data needs to be processed, these variable values need to be changed. As there are many scripts this duplication is annoying and error-prone. I would like to group all configuration variables into a single file.

I tried making `Config.py` which would contain them as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959638/276168), but `import Config` produces `ImportError: No module named Config` because they are not part of a package.

Then I tried relying on variable inheritance: define them once in `MainScript.py` which calls all the others. This works, but I realized that each script would not be able to run on its own. To solve this, I tried adding `useGlobal=True` in `MainScript.py` and in other files:

```
if (useGlobal is None or useGlobal==False):
  # define all variables
```

But this fails when scripts are run standalone: `NameError: name 'useGlobal' is not defined`. The workaround is to define useGlobal and set it to False when running the scripts independently of `MainScript.py`. It there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Since you don't have `Config` set up as a Module you can still import its information using: `from config import *`

Comment: That does not work either: `ImportError: No module named Config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by cleros, [ConfigParser module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) seems to be the closest thing to what I wanted (one-line statement in each file which would set up multiple variables).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a configuration file placed in your home directory (`~/.config/yourscript/config.json`).

You can then load the file on start and provide default values if the file does not exist :

Example (config.py) :

```
import json

default_config = {
    "name": "volnt",
    "mail": "oh@hi.com"
}

def load_settings():
    settings = default_config
    try:
        with open("~/.config/yourscript/config.json", "r") as config_file:
            loaded_config = json.loads(config_file.read())
            for key in loaded_config:
                settings[key] = loaded_config[key]
    except IOError: # file does not exist
        pass
    return settings
```

For a configuration file it's a good idea to use json and not python, because it makes it easy to edit for people using your scripts.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is there any advantage to this approach over ConfigParser module?

Comment: No, except that ConfigParser config files are using the .ini format.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that python wants to access files - including the Config.py - primarily as part of a module.

The nice thing is that Python makes building modules (i.e. python packages) really easy - initializing it can be done by creating a

```
__init__.py
```

file in each directory you want as a module, a submodule, a subsubmodule, and so on.

So your import should go through if you have created this file.

If you have further questions, look at the excellent [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

---

Comment: That should be `__init__.py`

Comment: Thanks - I noticed ... I forgot the auto-markup for underscore :-)

Comment: Creating `__init__.py` does not make the import error go away.

Comment: hmm, strange. Could you please give us the folder-structure of your project (so, where is config.py, `__init__py` and the python file for the import)? the problem could be related to importing something from another level of the package-structure.

Comment: And another option - which could be more elegant in the first place - could be the configparser package. Look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) for more information.

Comment: All the Python files (MainScript.py, Config.py, OtherFile.py etc) are in a single folder (called Batch). This folder contains some other files (Results.csv etc) and subfolders (Input1 etc), if that matters.