# Python 2.7 global variable issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7. Tried to import a global variable `counter` from `testlib.py`, in `uselib.py`, but return result is `0` in below program in `uselib.py`, why `2` is not returned? Thanks.

**testlib.py**,

```
counter = 0

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def Count(self):
        global counter
        counter += 1
```

**uselib.py**,

```
from testlib import Foo
from testlib import counter


f = Foo()
f.Count()

g = Foo()
g.Count()

print counter # output is 0 other than 2
```

Comment: I'm guessing it imports a copy to the current scope, so it doesn't modify the right `counter`

Comment: @AndrewL., what do you mean import a copy?

Comment: Related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/python-visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Python docs:

> The import statement combines two operations; it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope.

So, that implies that the `counter` you import is just a *copy* with a label imported into the current scope, meaning modification isn't happening on the right `counter`.

When you import `counter`, Python finds the module, takes the `counter` from `testlib`, then **copies** it to `uselib`. That copy is not modified because you're calls to `Count` modify the variable in `testlib`, not the copy you have added to the local scope by importing. This means you print the initial state of `counter`, but it never is modified, printing 0. To print correctly, use:

```
print testlib.counter
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, does it mean Python import a copy of counter in uselib.py, even before I call Foo.Count?

Comment: @LinMa when you write `from testlib import counter`, python searches for `testlib`, and when it finds it, it then finds the `counter` variable. Once it finds it, it copies `counter`'s initial value to `uselib`'s current scope. It's not the counter reference, but the *value*.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it copies before I call Foo.Count()?

Comment: Yes, it does. `Foo.Count()` modifies the `counter` in testlib, not the imported one

Comment: @LinMa If I did help please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Sure Andrew, this is what I just did. :)

Answer (score 1):

`from testlib import counter` introduces a *copy* of `counter`. As integer type is immutable, this imported `counter` would not be affected by operations inside `testlib`.

You could try something like this instead:

```
import testlib
print testlib.counter
```

Comment: Cool starrify! It works!