# Python: variables shared betwen modules and namespaces

Tags: python, module, global-variables

After reading at 
[Python - Visibility of global variables in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/python-visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules)

I was curious about this example:

```
import shared_stuff
import module1

shared_stuff.a = 3
module1.f()
```

If there are no other variables "a" anywhere else, why the following one is not equivalent?

```
from shared_stuff import *
import module1

a = 3
module1.f()
```

We leave out "explicit is better than implicit": I am asking out of curiosity, as I prefer the first syntax anyway. 
I come from C and it looks like I didn't fully grasp Python's namespace's subtleties. 
Even a link to docs where this namespace's behaviour is explained is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing `*` copies all the references from the module into the current scope; there is no connection to the original module at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. I believed it also kept the link to the module. Thank you.