# Access numpy array (vs. python array) from another module

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, global-variables, local-variables

I am tryint to convert some of my python arrays to numpy arrays and have problems accessing a supposingly global np array in another module.

Module 1 (imports data):

```
import numpy as np
jobs_db = []

def read_all_data(date, filepath):

    global jobs_db
    jobs_db =          np.loadtxt(filepath+'jobs_input.csv', dtype=np.uint8, delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
```

Module 2 (uses data):

```
from Import_data import *

if __name__ == '__main__':

     read_all_data(180901, 'C:/Users/*********/')
     print(jobs_db)
```

However, when I execute the main method, the console shows an empty array while the array contains data when calling it whithin module 1. The problem does not occur if I use a python array instead of a numpy array.

Comment: Why are you using global variables here at all? Just return it from your function

Comment: Anyway, this is because you are using a starred import, which is essentially equivalent to `import Import_data; jobs_db = Import_data.jobs_db`, but now `jobs_db` has nothing to do with `Import_data.jobs_db`, except they happen to refer to the same object, but can be made to refer to other objects independently. Use the module, so `Import_data.jobs_db`, or better yet, don't use a global variable at all

Comment: But how come it works with a python array and not a numpy array?

Comment: What do you mean? It works in exactly the same way.

Comment: Try it for yourself, make your function just do `jobs_db = ['foo', 'bar']`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, you're right, it works the same way if I do `jobs_db = ['foo', 'bar']` (the array is still empty in my Module 2. However, if i try `jobs_db.append(['foo','bar'])`, it shows the content in my module 2.

Comment: yes, of course, because the two *different variables* are happening to refer to the *same object*. But assignment to different another object won't affect the other variable. It's the same as `a = 'foo'; b = a; a = 'bar'; print(b)` will print `foo`

Comment: But again, you shouldn't be using global variables to begin with. It is a really bad practice leading to hard to maintain and hard to understand code. *Especially* if you are using mutable global state. Have a couple global "constants" can be forgiven, code relying on mutable global state should not pass any sensible code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question with explanation can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules)

For my problem specifically, I should have imported the module 1 by stating `import Import_data` instead of `from Import_data import *` and then using `Import_data.jobs_db` to access the variable.