# NameError DataFrame is not defined when importing class

Tags: python, class

I recently learned about the `np.select` operation and decided to create a class to experiment with it and also learn a bit more on OOP.

Here the definition of my class followed by an example (the class uses the `translate` function defined at the beginning):

```
def translate(text, conversion_dict, before = None):
    if not text: return text
    before = before or str.lower
    t = before(text)
    for key, value in conversion_dict.items():
        t = t.replace(key, value)
    return t

class Conditions:
    def __init__(self, base_conditions, composed_conditions, groups, default_group):
        self.base_conditions = base_conditions
        self.composed_conditions = composed_conditions
        self.groups = groups
        self.default_group = default_group
        self.readable_conditions = [translate(c, self.base_conditions) for c in self.composed_conditions]
        self.ok_conditions = []  

    def run_condition(self, condition, df_name):
        return eval(condition.replace("(","("+str(df_name)+"."))

    def run_conditions(self, df_name):
        return [self.run_condition(c, df_name) for c in  self.readable_conditions]
```

**Example**

First, we create a simple DataFrame to play with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

example = {"lev1" : [-1, -1, -1, 1, 0 , -1, 0 , 3],
           "lev2" : [-1, 0 , 1 , 5 , 0 , 7 , 8 , 6]}

ex_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example)
print(ex_df)

   lev1  lev2
0    -1    -1
1    -1     0
2    -1     1
3     1     5
4     0     0
5    -1     7
6     0     8
7     3     6
```

Next, we create a new instance of our class where we pass our conditions and groups:

```
mycond = Conditions({"(m1)" : "(lev1 < 0)",
                     "(m2)" : "(lev2 > 2)", 
                     "(m3)" : "(lev1 == 0)"},
                    ["(m1)", "(m2) & (m3)", "(m2)"],
                    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    999)
```

Finally, we use the `np.select` operation on our `ex_df` DataFrame and print the result:

```
ex_df['MATCH'] = np.select(condlist = mycond.run_conditions("ex_df"), 
                           choicelist = mycond.groups, 
                           default = mycond.default_group) 
print(ex_df)

   lev1  lev2 MATCH
0    -1    -1     A
1    -1     0     A
2    -1     1     A
3     1     5     C
4     0     0   999
5    -1     7     A
6     0     8     B
7     3     6     C
```

As you can see, everything works well with one exception.

When I tried to import my class from a separate file (`conditions.py` which also contains the `translate function`) it does not work anymore. Here is how my folders/files are organized:

```
├── classes
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── conditions.py
└── test-notebook.ipynb
```

In my `test-notebook.ipynb`, I import my class the usual way (which works):

```
from classes.conditions import *
```

Then, after creating my DataFrame, I create a new instance of my class (that also works). Finally, when a run the `np.select` operation this raises the following `NameError: name 'ex_df' is not defined`.

I have no idea **why** this outputs an error and **how** to fix it. I'm looking for an answer on both the **why** and **how**. Here's the traceback of the error if needed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1d4b3ba4a3c0> in <module>
----> 1 ex_df['MATCH'] = np.select(condlist = mycond.run_conditions("ex_df"), 
      2                            choicelist = mycond.groups,
      3                            default = mycond.default_group) 
      4 print(ex_df)

~/Projects/test/notebooks/classes/conditions.py in run_conditions(self, df_name)
     20 
     21     def run_conditions(self, df_name):
---> 22         return [self.run_condition(c, df_name) for c in  self.readable_conditions]

~/Projects/test/notebooks/classes/conditions.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     20 
     21     def run_conditions(self, df_name):
---> 22         return [self.run_condition(c, df_name) for c in  self.readable_conditions]

~/Projects/test/notebooks/classes/conditions.py in run_condition(self, condition, df_name)
     17 
     18     def run_condition(self, condition, df_name):
---> 19         return eval(condition.replace("(","("+str(df_name)+"."))
     20 
     21     def run_conditions(self, df_name):

~/Projects/test/notebooks/classes/conditions.py in <module>

NameError: name 'ex_df' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context, the variable `ex_df` is not accessible as a global or local variable, ie, the function `run_conditions` knows the name "ex_df" but doesn't know what it is.

You need to pass the reference to the DataFrame instead of its name:

```
ex_df['MATCH'] = np.select(condlist = mycond.run_conditions(ex_df), 
                           choicelist = mycond.groups, 
                           default = mycond.default_group)
```

Then change the definition of `run_condition` to accept the DataFrame instead of a variable name:

```
def run_condition(self, condition, df):
    return eval(condition.replace("(","(df."))

def run_conditions(self, df):
    return [self.run_condition(c, df) for c in  self.readable_conditions]
```

**Explanation:** Inside the context of the function `run_condition`, the variable name is `df`. There is no "ex_df" - that is just how you called it somewhere else. Running eval() at that point, the interpreter knows `df` by that name, which is an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve the problem

FIRST FILE NAME Stackoverflow2.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def translate(text, conversion_dict, before = None):
    if not text: return text
    before = before or str.lower
    t = before(text)
    for key, value in conversion_dict.items():
        t = t.replace(key, value)
    return t

class Conditions:
    def __init__(self, base_conditions, composed_conditions, groups, default_group):
        self.base_conditions = base_conditions
        self.composed_conditions = composed_conditions
        self.groups = groups
        self.default_group = default_group
        self.readable_conditions = [translate(c, self.base_conditions) for c in self.composed_conditions]
        self.ok_conditions = []  

    def run_condition(self, condition, df_name):
        return eval(condition.replace("(","("+str(df_name)+"."))

    def run_conditions(self, df_name):
        return [self.run_condition(c, df_name) for c in  self.readable_conditions]

class DataFrame(Conditions):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def makeDataFrame(self):

        example = {"lev1" : [-1, -1, -1, 1, 0 , -1, 0 , 3],
        "lev2" : [-1, 0 , 1 , 5 , 0 , 7 , 8 , 6]}

        ex_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example)

        return ex_df



obj=DataFrame()

print(obj.makeDataFrame())

# mycond = Conditions({"(m1)" : "(lev1 < 0)",
#                      "(m2)" : "(lev2 > 2)", 
#                      "(m3)" : "(lev1 == 0)"},
#                     ["(m1)", "(m2) & (m3)", "(m2)"],
#                     ['A', 'B', 'C'],
#                     999)

# ex_df['MATCH'] = np.select(condlist = mycond.run_conditions("ex_df"), 
#                            choicelist = mycond.groups, 
#                            default = mycond.default_group) 
# print(ex_df)
```

SECOND FILE NAME: Stackoverflow3.py

```
from Stackoverflow2 import *

print(obj.makeDataFrame())
```

The problem is the global variables in python does work as in c or c++.
So instead make them an instance variables.

for further info check this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules
```