# Python 3 and global variable in module

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, module, global

main1.py

```
import mya
a=10
mya.increment_a()
a=a-5
print(a)
```

module mya.py

```
def increment_a():
    global a

    a=a+1
    print(a)
```

name 'a' is not defined.
I don't understand why. I declare variable a as global in module, so from this point a=0 as it is in mail1.py
upd: I need work globaly. Starting value for variable "a" set in main.py, function in module mya.py will edit "a", and return new value to main.py for further use.
--- closed topic---
Now I use "arguments" and "return" and in work:

mya.py

```
def increment_a(a):
    a=a+1
    print(a)
    return a
```

main1.py

```
import mya
a=0
print(a)
a=mya.increment_a(a)
a=a+10
print(a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visibility of global variables in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules)

Comment: I need work with "a" globally. Starting value for variable "a" set in main.py, function in module mya.py will edit "a", and return new value to main.py.

Comment: @RedSubmarine no, you don't *need* to, and indeed, it is considered an anti-pattern to rely on global mutable state. Python itself doesn't support true global variables, global means "module level global". The best solution is to improve your design to avoid global mutable state

Comment: So only way to work globally is move all function from mya.py to main1.py?

Comment: @RedSubmarine or you could work directly on the module in `main1.py`, so `mya.a = foo` etc. But again, this is all a terrible practice. Don't do any of this.

Comment: Ok. Arguments and return worked: 
#---mya.py
def increment_a(a):
    a=a+1
    print(a)
    return a

#---main1.py
import mya
a=0
print(a)
a=mya.increment_a(a)
a=a+10
print(a)

Answer (score 0):

From [Visibility of global variables in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules):

> Globals in Python are global to a module, not across all modules. (Many people are confused by this, because in, say, C, a global is the same across all implementation files unless you explicitly make it `static`.)

One approach to deal with it is:

```py
import mya
mya.a=3
mya.increment_a()
```

Comment: Since you identified that the question is a duplicate, there is no need for you to post an answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure how this works, so just in case. Should I delete it?

Comment: I read all related topics and has no understanding of this situation. Yes this approach can fix error. But I need work with variable a not only in module. I need work globaly. Starting value for variable "a" set in main.py, function in module mya.py will edit "a", and return new value to main.py. For suggested approach it will not work.

Comment: @RedSubmarine the best solution is not to rely on global mutable state. So, either write your functions to take data in as arguments and return data as return values, or write a class to encapsulate state, and use instances of that class in your modules.

Comment: The linked post suggests some alternatives, like setting attributes in the namespace of a separately imported module `shared_stuff`, and have other modules import it, too.