# calling a function in the __main__ file from an imported file

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I am trying to find a way to call a function in the __main__ file from a file that i have imported at the top. I do not want to have to add in a import for the __main__ file into the file i am importing into the __main__ file since i want this to work for and file that imports it. Here's an example

main file:

```
import importedFile

def Function():
    print("test")
```

and what I want the imported file to do, this code does not work but it explains what I want to do:

```
__main__.Function()
```

Comment: _I am trying to find a way to call a function in the main file from a file that i have imported at the top. I do not want to have to add in a import for the main file into the file i am importing into the main file since i want this to work for and file that imports it._ Can you rephrase this? It's tough to keep track of what's going on.

Comment: Please use PEP8 standards!

Comment: You have to import it.

Comment: Or this? [Visibility of global variables in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15959534/7509065)

Comment: So i have the main file that i click run on, and at the top it is importing another file. I would like the file that is imported to be able to run commands on the main file. I hope this is a bit more clear.

Comment: `__main__` is the name of the module, as in `"__main__"`

Comment: Would there be a way to access the functions in the "____main____" module?

Comment: Yes. *import them*. `import whatever; whatever.Function()`

Comment: `from main import Function`

Comment: i have tried `import __main__` but it dosn't seem to work.

Comment: Why do you think that would work? What's the name of the file?

Comment: currently the name of the file is "test", but i would like it to work no matter what the file name is

Comment: _but i would like it to work no matter what the file name is_ Can you be more specific? Have you read any guides, or the documentation, on the organization of Python programs and their dependencies?

Comment: There's no way for two files to import each other. You have to put `Function` into a 3rd file and have both files import that.