# Reset dictionary in python not working from a module

Tags: python, dictionary, global

I am very puzzled by this strange behavior. I have a file called test.py containing the following:

```
X={}

def fun():
    global X
    X = {'a':1,'b':2}
```

then I import the file as a module from the console and call the function

```
from test import *
fun()
```

I would expect `X` to be updated but it is still an empty dictionary.
I am using

Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26)

is anybody able to reproduce this? Do you know why it happens?

Thanks.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules

Answer (score 0):

In the second file, the `X` object is imported and bound to a name at the time `import` runs. The `X` in the second file is a second name attached to the original `{}`. Or, in other words, it's a separate variable that just happens to have the same name as the `X` in the original file.

Changing the `X` label in the original file won't change what object the `X` in the second file is looking at, because they're distinct labels (with the same name).

It's similar to how this doesn't change `Y`:

```
X = {}
Y = X  # Y is the "imported X"
X = {'a':1,'b':2}
```