# Import custom function in python file

Tags: python, import

Hi I'm confused by importing functions form another .py file

My question is this

I made two .py files

First one named `qq.py`

```
def bb(x):
    x = aa(x)
    return x+3
def aa(x):
    return x+ 6
```

Second one named `test.py`

```
from qq import bb
print(bb(10))
```

*add comment : `test.py` worked

I thought that `test.py` wouldn't work.
Because function `bb` requires function `aa` and function `aa` didn't imported

Why this worked?

Thank you.

Comment: Code in the module runs in the module's namespace, not the importer's namespace, so it can refer to other code in the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563392/visibility-of-global-variable-declared-in-imported-module) I posted a few days ago.
Basically, when you import bb in test.py, it brings along a reference to the namespace of the module where bb was defined.
So, in test.py, if you try:

```
from qq import bb
for x in bb.__globals__:
    print(x)
```

you'll get the output:

```
__name__
__doc__
__package__
__loader__
__spec__
__file__
__cached__
__builtins__
bb
aa
```

So, you can see that both bb and aa are recognized in test.py.

Answer (score 1):

It will work because python just need the child function and it will call its dependency automatically