# Using global variables when importing functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import openpyxl as pyxl
from functions import myFunction

wb = pyxl.load_workbook("data.xlsx")
myDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=rows)
```

The code below works, when I pass in the workbook and dataframe

```
myFunction(wb, myDF)
```

but if it doesn't work if I declare global variables within the import function, getting an error of 'NameError: name 'wb' is not defined.' so I don't believe it's recognising the global variable from the main script. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
#from the imported code
myFunction():
  global wb
  global myDF
  ws = wb['Sheet1']

#run from the main script
myFunction()
```

Comment: Not sure if I get what you're saying: So, the variables `wb` and `myDF` are in the same file as `myFunction`? If not, did you import them into the same file?

Comment: `wb` and `myDF` come from the global scope where `myFunction` is *defined*, not the one where it is *called*. "Global" is a bit of a misnomer, in that every module has its own global scope; the only program-wide scope in Python is the built-in scope (which is effectively a read-only scope; you cannot add names to it).

Comment: Because global means module global. When you do `from module import x` that creates a new variable `x` in the module doing the importing, but global modifications in the imported module affect `module.x`. here's the good news: this is a *good thing* and the approach you were trying to take is an antipattern to begin with

Comment: Don't use that approach. Don't use `global`. Use parameters and return values like every experienced programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Globals in Python are global to a module, not across all modules. as explained in this answer [Visibility of global variables in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules)

So you have to put this code inside your functions in order to work:

```
import openpyxl as pyxl
import pandas as pd

wb = pyxl.load_workbook("data.xlsx")
cols=['A','B'] #for example purposes
rows=range(1,10) #for example purposes
myDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=rows)

def myFunction(): 
    global wb
    global myDF
    ws = wb['Sheet1']
```

And in your main module

```
from functions import myFunction

myFunction()
```