# Python error when using an object from a script in a function imported from another script

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

In a file `a.py` I have the following code:

```
# a.py

def test():
    global i
    print(f'The number is {i}')
```

So, in a file `b.py` I imported `a.py`:

```
# b.py

from a import *

i = 22

test()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

I thought this would work, once the function was imported, and, object i was defined in b.py. How do I resolve this?

Comment: See this overflow response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959534/visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to note.

First, import * is not encouraged as it brings a lot of modules over that you might have no interest in. It is why you will often see particular imports from modules.

Second, a globally declared variable is global only in the context of the module a. When you import *, you have imported a variable called i from a, referenced in code as a.i. To get this to work, you can alter your b.py code to the following

```
import a
a.i = 22
a.test()
```

The issue with your code is you are declaring i in module b which module a has no capability of referencing - global is only global within a module. So by declaring a.i = 22, you are telling module a that its global i value is now 22.

I would say better way to approach this would be to make your function take in an argument i and have no need to reference a specific within the module itself, but I don't know your use case. I will add the code below regardless!

a.py

```
def test(i):
    print(f'The number is {i}')
```

b.py

```
from a import test

i = 22
test(i)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to use `import *`, it is very generic (and wont work in your case), you can do this instead :

```
import a

a.i = 22

a.test()
```

output:

```
The number is 22
```