Importing py file/s into google colab notebook
I tried searching but couldnt find the right solution. Please point me to it if I missed it.
I have a google colab notebook like below. I will describe my issue alongside the code description.
First, mount the drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

Append a folder to path. In this folder, I have py file called multiFunc.py which has 4 functions defined
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/temp')

Import multiFunc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import multiFunc

So far it is good but I have some issues with some of the functions. multiFunc.py file is shown at the bottom. First two functions work for me but the last two dont. Of course if I include all these functions in the section of the same colab notebook, everything works.
First function works fine and gives correct output and prints 8
print(multiFunc.TestAdd(2,6))

Second function also works fine and prints text jpg
print(multiFunc.ReturnExt('abcd.jpg'))

The third function does not work and complaints that no plt found. I have imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt in the main colab notebook and would like it to take effect but unless I include it in the function py file, it doesnt work. Any way to make this work?
img = multiFunc.ReturnImage('image path')

In the fourth function, I am trying to change a global variable inside the function and it doesnt work. I would like the global variable b to become 10 but it doesnt. The argument to this function doesnt do anything, I just have it.
b = 5
multiFunc.ChangeGlobal(2)

Here is the content of multiFunc.py
def TestAdd(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

def ReturnExt(filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return ext

def ReturnImage(path):
  im = plt.imread(path)
  return im

def ChangeGlobal(a):
  global b
  b = 10

Any help is much appreciated.
regards!

Is there are reason you don't want to import matplotlib in your multiFunc module? As far as I know this is a must for "all" programming languages (importing modules into the file where you are using it). If you don't call plt in your main file, you don't have to import it there, but you need to import it in the multiFunc since you are doing a call to it there. You can of course import it in both places, just don't use from multiFunc import *
As for you second question, checkout this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959638/21134500
