# Parse a user input to a function to fetch from another file

Tags: python, python-2.x

So I have 2 files , file1.py and file2.py

I have a couple of lists sam and dan from file2.py

so when I try this from file1.py I get

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myvar'
```

**file1.py**

```
import file2

f_var=[]
myvar = raw_input("some string")

if myvar == "sam":
    f_var = loopbov("sam")


def loopbov(myvar):
    lst=[]
    for each in file2.myvar:
        te = fet(each):
        lst.append(te)
    return lst

def fet(vpf):
    tmp=[]
    # this gets me an list as an output
    return tmp
```

**file2.py**

```
sam=["33:89","21:70"]
dan=["34:43","23:56"]
```

I know it's a simple error but can someone explain how to access by parsing a object here to access from another file

Comment: `file2` doesn't have a `myvar` field. It has `sam` and `dan`. Give it a try to `for each in getattr(file2, myvar):` (and check [this about getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) )

Comment: #1, show how you are running the code. #2, what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: @BorrajaX. Sorry about the last comment. Deleted it. You should draft an answer explaining why and how.

Comment: @BorrajaX It worked,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in `file2.py` there are two variables defined, right? `sam` and `dan`.

You can see that taking advantage than in Python, everything is an object:

```
import file2
print("This is what I found in file2:\n%s" % vars(file2))
```

You'll see a looot of stuff, but among other things, you will see your `sam` and `dan` variables. There is no `myvar` name, right? In your question `file1.py`'s `myvar` will contain *the name* of the variable that you want to access...

And here's where [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) comes in: Given an instance, how can you get one of its fields if you know its name (if you have the name stored in a string). Like this: `getattr(file2, myvar)`

So your `loopbov` function, where you pass the name of the list to iterate in the `myvar` argument would become:

```
def loopbov(myvar):
    lst=[]
    for each in getattr(file2, myvar):
        # myvar will be the string `"sam"`
        te = fet(each):
        lst.append(te)
    return lst
```

As @MadPhysicist mentioned in his comment, it's probably worth mentioning what `getattr` will do when it's trying to get an attribute by name that is not defined: You will get an `AttributeError` exception. Try it. Put somewhere in your `file1.py` this code: `getattr(file2, "foobar")` However! If you see the docs for `getattr` you will see that accepts an optional argument: `default`. That can be read like *"ok, if I don't find the attribute, I won't give you an error, but that `default` argument"*.

Probably it's also worth it reading a bit, if you're interested in the subject, about how import works and the namespaces it creates (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890014/python-namespaces-with-module-imports) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html))

Comment: Sorry I accidentally clobbered your edits for a second there.

Comment: Haha, no worries!! I tend to edit over and over and over. Appreciate the edits!

Comment: You might want to mention the optional extra argument to getattr, or the possibility of an `AttributeError`  in the case where the user enters something besides `'sam'` or `'dan'`.

Comment: Got that covered guys, it's part of a larger code was just stuck here and 'Sam' and 'Dan'  are actually a list gathered out of json response ;)

Answer (score 0):

In `file2.py` use a dictionary:

```
my_vars = {'sam': ["33:89","21:70"], 
           'dan': ["34:43","23:56"]}
```

Now, in `file1.py`:

```
import file2

def loopbov(myvar):
    lst=[]
    for each in file2.my_vars[myvar]:
        te = fet(each)
        lst.append(te)
    return lst

def fet(vpf):
    tmp=[]
    # this gets me an list as an output
    return tmp


f_var = loopbov("sam")
```

Comment: The module is already a dictionary to all intents and purposes. Why the overkill?

Comment: Feels cleaner to use a dict instead of working with 'getattr`or `vars`.

Comment: Thanks will keep it in mind , but getattr served my purpose here.